# How To Update MySQL Based On Field That Changed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I have made a program where it displays ONE field - Title and Description.

If the user wants another 'row' it will click 'add row' and I made a Javascript Function To add another row.

Everything like title[] and description are in an array in the  Section

The program then automatically displays every entry entered by using a mysql_query to extract into varaible and then an echo to display the inputs .

Although the problem here is, how can I get the program to know which field I have edited? lets say I only edited Title[3] and Description [3] to update those field only?

```
if ($submit2) {
    $numberofURLS = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM urls WHERE name='Daniel12'"));
    echo "Number Of URLS: " . $numberofURLS;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($numberofURLS); $i++) {
    $theTitle = $site_title[$i];
    $theDesc = $site_description[$i];
    $theURL = $site_url[$i];
    mysql_query("UPDATE urls SET title=$theTitle, description=$theDesc, url=$theURL WHERE name=Daniel12");
```

- plus an input submit2 button

I have done something like this although It updates every title / description / url to the first [0].

Is there another technical way I can do this that is potentially simpler?

Comment: Are you using AJAX here to update?

Comment: @Novice Using PHP

Comment: you need to put the id of the row in your form.  edit your post to include the HTML, that would probably help.